# Apache reverse proxy with spring boot on 443

Tags: spring-boot, apache, reverse-proxy

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and I need to use a reverse proxy to redirect 8080 to 443 so I can access like https://example.com but I don't seem to get the correct configuration and I keep getting a 500 error.

After a lot of searching I'm not able to find the root of the error. While reading I came up with the following configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` (letsencrypt edited the last few lines of each virtual host).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ProxyRequests Off
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mysite.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysite.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8080/
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing?

BTW: accessing http://example.com:8080 works fine

*Edit: I already have ssl and proxy modules loaded*

*Edit 2: if I run `a2ensite default-ssl` and then I get the apache page with https. I tried migrating my config to that file but still fails but only when adding this line: `ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/`, other configuration still loads the apache website*

Comment: An http status 500 is just the generic information the http server hands out to requesting clients. It does not contain any details about the actual issue for obvious security reasons. You as the operator need to learn about those details, so the bause of the issue. For that you need to take a look into your http server's error log file. What do you find in there? I would expect that one or both required proxy modules are missing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually missing one of this three mods: `proxy`, `proxy_http`, or `ssl`. After this, everything worked.